# On executing batch file capture command prompt logs and save a backup of those logs in file using Java

Tags: java

To print the logs in file I used the below code,, but I not able to print "System.out.println" statement which exists in batch file code.

```
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p1 = runtime.exec("C:\\Users\\mf11131\\Desktop\\Batch\\SimpleBatch.bat");
    java.io.InputStream is = (java.io.InputStream) p1.getInputStream();
    File logfile = new File("C:\\logs\\Logfile.txt");
    FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(logfile);
    int i = 0;
    while((i = is.read()) != -1)
    {
        fop.write((char)i);
    }
```

Below is the simple code of batch file.

```
class abc
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     int count=0;
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
        System.out.println("hi hello"+count);
     }
   }
}
```

I need output like below command prompt logs[image]

My current output is[image]

Comment: post your batch files code and what exactly your desired output is in the log file

Comment: I dont think it will work with `BAT` file like that.

Comment: What are the contents of "SimpleBatch.bat" file? You have provided SimpleBatch.java.

Comment: Contents of "SimpleBatch.bat" file is just I created batch file for above Java class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all of the output into a file you should use stream redirection like this

```
byBatFile.bat > logFile.
```

This will cause all the output to be stored into `logFile`.

I have my doubts about possibility to get stdio streams of invoked applications inside batch script. I think that IO is separated in manners you would like to use it.

On the other hand, your batch script "spawns" new processes on every command. You could try to `call` those processes insteed of spawning new ones like this

```
call javac abc.java
call java abc
```

Comment: But I shouldn't manually type the commands in Prompt. So when particular batch file runs need to keep a backup of those logs automatically in local system.

Comment: And where did I write that you have to type that manually? Just put `call`s in bat file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this as I done a mistake of pointing directory to Java class directory while creating a Batch file. So only Java (System.out.println) statements are not printing.